# error in applying pre-trained model for english of maltparser

Tags: forms, parsing, nlp, text-parsing

I'm embarking on **maltparser**. I want to apply the offered

**pre-trained model** ['engmalt.linear-1.7'](http://www.maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.html) to parsing

**english** sentence on **command line**.

I download the **engmalt** and changed its file name from

'engmalt.linear-1.7.**zip**' to 'engmalt.linear-1.7.**mco**'. I

save the **example english sentence** (on engmalt's download page)

in 'infile.conll' and run on command line.

I can't get the result and there's a strange **error**:

> No label symbol available for label 'FORM'.

(By the way, if I test the '/maltparser-

1.7.1/examples/data/talbanken05_test.conll' of maltparser

package,it can surprisingly get the dependency! )

- Q1: Should I change the filename extension of 'engmalt.linear'?
- Q2: Why I can use engmalt to parse 'talbanken05_test.conll'(not

english sentence)?

- Q3:Why there's an error when I parse english sentence?What does

it mean?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you sure you have tabs separating the columns in the sentence you copied from the download page?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, and I'm not sure the OP still wants an answer. The correct format you should use with the pre-trained model is the ten column format which is defined in this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataformat name="conllx">
    <column name="ID" category="INPUT" type="INTEGER"/>
    <column name="FORM" category="INPUT" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="LEMMA" category="INPUT" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="CPOSTAG" category="INPUT" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="POSTAG" category="INPUT" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="FEATS" category="INPUT" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="HEAD" category="HEAD" type="INTEGER"/>
    <column name="DEPREL" category="DEPENDENCY_EDGE_LABEL" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="PHEAD" category="IGNORE" type="INTEGER" default="_"/>
    <column name="PDEPREL" category="IGNORE" type="STRING" default="_"/>

</dataformat>
```